# Android kotlin Change field names in class (but also keep the old ones -> be able to switch between them)

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I have situation where I have next class:

```
    data class LoginBody(
    var username: String,
    var password: String,
    var deviceType: String,
    var deliveryPlatform: String,
    var osName: String,
    var deviceId: String
)
```

This class is propagated through all application and is used on various places. I have now demand to implement changes in my data class. It should now look like this:

```
data class LoginBody(
    var username: String,
    var password: String,
    var device_type: String,
    var client_platform: String,
    var os_name: String,
    var device_id: String
)
```

But I have to keep both implementations and sometimes when app starts I should use first option and sometimes second.

I can solve this. Creating other class with different name and connecting these 2 classes with interface. After that call interface in all the places in the app where I used to call the class.
In this case it looks like overkill since the first implementation will die immediately after the testing on production is done.

I would like to have nice solution like for example with converting function in my LoginBody data class:

```
fun LoginBody.convertToNewLoginBody(shouldConvert: Boolean) = ....
```

But I feel like this solution is impossible. Before starting with implementation that I wrote above, I decided to ask here to see if anyone has idea how to solve it with extension function or with some similar way (if it is actually possible). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use Refactor in Android Studio?

Comment: @CCT don't understand, what do you mean by "Refactor". what steps to take?

Comment: Refractor is, renaming the variable names.. Why don't you create only one class. Is it because of databases?

Comment: @SohaibAhmed I can not. Because both my classes should be used. Imagine user has a switch in the app. When in one position I use first implementation of LoginBody. If in position two, I use second implementation of LoginBody.
Note here that only field names are changed.

Comment: You are using `LoginBody` for Retrofit? So it's why you want to keep both of them?

Comment: I use LoginBody as a body class in my Api call. (Yes I use retrofit). I must keep both of them because I shoot 2 api endpoints with those 2 bodies.